# What is the proper way to write a file path in python to execute script onto that file?

Tags: python, string, filepath

I have a python script which I would like to execute onto a file. I have a function in the script called def parse(file_path, nan_values=None):
I need to replace the file_path with a txt file that is saved on my mac (in Downloads). 
What is the syntax for writing a path to file in string form?

Comment: That depends. In part it depends upon how you invoke the python script. How do you invoke the Python script?

Comment: Probably as an input argument from the command line via `sys.argv`

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by how I invoke it. I'm using pycharm

Comment: @Suever how would I do that in pycharm?

Comment: @user8669 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33102272/pycharm-and-sys-argv-arguments