# IDEA python file list script parameter is not expanded

Tags: python, intellij-idea, parameters, runtime

I want to run a python script from within IntelliJ IDEA passing a file list as a parameter. I'm using menu Run->Edit Configurations->Script Parameters to define a file list using wildcards like: `"../examples/*.jpg"`

Inside the code I'm iterating the file list using a for loop like

```
for f in sys.argv[1:]:
```

Although the script executes fine from terminal, IDEA throws a file not found exception:

```
No such file or directory: '../examples/*.jpg'
```

I suppose this makes sense (my theory) since there is no shell involved to expand the command line argument into a file list prior passing it to the script.

There is an answer in a similar question here: [Pycharm and sys.argv arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33102272/pycharm-and-sys-argv-arguments)
The relevant answer using wildcards is https://stackoverflow.com/a/41003295/7521854 but it is not working. *(If I had enough rep I'd commented on this answer, sorry)*

Any suggestion will make me happy!

PS: running OSX 10.11.6 (El Capitan)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding wildcards in the command line parameters is the feature of the command line shell / terminal. IDE doesn't use the command line shell when starting your application, therefore parameters are not expanded. Related request:

- [IDEA-163811](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-163811) Allow wildcards in script parameters

Comment: As I said, this makes sense. I'm just looking for a way / a trick to overcome this limitation.

Comment: You can't overcome it using the standard run/debug configuration, you will need to run via Terminal or use some wrapper script which will expand the args and pass them to your script.