# Is there a way to do Shell Expansion of Program arguments in Goland?

Tags: go, goland

Say I have a bunch of `.txt` files, and a go file `fn.go` to read their name.  I can type `./fn *.txt` in shell to run `fn.go` properly (`os.Args` will include `a.txt`, `b.txt` etc due to [shell expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html)).

However if I set "Program Arugments" to `*.txt` in goland:

[image: goland screenshot]

then this does not work because goland won't do Shell Expansion to expand `*.txt` to `a.txt b.txt` which are passed to `fn`. Is there a workaroud?

I tried search the internet,but no luck

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you actually mean. Simplify your sentences

Comment: Note that your question is OS specific (e.g. windows `cmd.exe` does not do this kind of shell expansion). I don't believe that this is a feature of GoLand (or [the other IDEA based tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43865950/idea-python-file-list-script-parameter-is-not-expanded/))

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `os.ReadDir()` function not to pass all these files as command-line arguments:

```
files, err := os.ReadDir(".")
...
for _, f := range files {
...
}
```

Comment: thx,that's a nice workaround