# PyCharm error: List index out of range

Tags: python

I got list index out of range error in `with open(sys.argv[1],'r') as input:`
I found one answer in StackOverflow, "just make sure to pass a command line argument when you run the script". But still not working. Can anyone help me with it?

Here is my code:

```
from collections import Counter
import sys

newList = []

with open(sys.argv[1],'r') as input:
    for element in input:
        temp = str(element).rstrip("\n")
        temphex = (int(temp,16))
        newList.append(temphex)

veryNew=sorted(newList)

for n in range(len(veryNew)):
    veryNew[n] = hex(veryNew[n])[2:]
    sortedHex = veryNew

d={}
for item in veryNew:
    if item in d:
        d[item] = d.get(item)+1
    else:
        d[item]=1


for k,v in d.items():
    if v > 1:
        print(str(k)+' '+str(v))
```

Comment: The problem is how you're running the script, which you haven't shown us.  It should be something like `python myscript.py file.txt`

Comment: I edited your question to fix the formatting of the code.  Please ensure that what appears now matches what you're trying to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PyCharm, when you need parameters from `sys.argv`, you should run the code with **script parameters**, see details on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33102415/8584830). I think `sys.argv` list alters between different IDEs.

If you run like this:

`python test.py`, you will get `sys.argv = ['python', 'test.py']`

else if

`./test.py filename`, you will get `sys.argv = ['./test.py', 'filename']`

Also, my another advice: try to use a terminal to run code, because sometimes IED just do what should do without letting you know.

Comment: Also highly recommend `if __name__ == "__main__":`

Answer (score 0):

Show us how are you running the script. Are you passing any arguments to the script?

`argv[1]` is the first argument after script name.

running script like `python myscript.py`, which how pycharm runs it if you didn't change it, gets you `['myscript.py']` in `argv`, that is, `argv[0]` is `'myscript.py'` and `argv[1]` is out of range.

running script like for example `python myscript.py file.txt` will get you `['myscript.py', 'file.txt']` in `argv` list.

Comment: Yes, I run the script like "python3 myscript.py file.txt" in cmd, but I got error :"[Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Comment: well, does file.txt exist in current directory? I assume that you have some file with multiple lines of hex values. That file have to be in working directory (directory where you run the script) or you have to specify absolute / relative path to it.

Comment: I did print the correct output in cmd. But the IDE still show me the error, does it matters?

Comment: If you want to run the script from IDE, you will have to find how the IDE runs the script - what is the working directory, and how to set command line arguments when running script from IDE. I have no experience with pycharm. Maybe refer to anwer from Yaosen Min and their link to another answer