# Python argparse: Too few arguments

Tags: python, pycharm, argparse

Here's my code:

```
def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Simple training script for object detection from a CSV file.')
    parser.add_argument('csv_path', help='Path to CSV file')
    parser.add_argument('--weights', help='Weights to use for initialization (defaults to ImageNet).', default='imagenet')
    parser.add_argument('--batch-size', help='Size of the batches.', default=1, type=int)

    return parser.parse_args()
```

when I run my code, I get an error:

```
usage: Train.py [-h] [--weights WEIGHTS] [--batch-size BATCH_SIZE] csv_path
Train.py: error: too few arguments
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Apparently you're using too few arguments when you run your program. What arguments are you using?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33102272/pycharm-and-sys-argv-arguments - sounds like you don't know how to call a script with commandline arguments.  Here's a SO on how to do that in `pycharm`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you did not specify the number of arguments expected after each flag  with `nargs` as such:

```
import argparse

def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Simple training script for object detection from a CSV file.')
    parser.add_argument('csv_path', nargs="?", type=str, help='Path to CSV file')
    parser.add_argument('--weights', nargs="?", help='Weights to use for initialization (defaults to ImageNet).', default='imagenet')
    parser.add_argument('--batch-size', nargs="?", help='Size of the batches.', default=1, type=int)

    return parser.parse_args()
parse_args()
```

According to the doc:

`If the nargs keyword argument is not provided, the number of arguments consumed is determined by the action. Generally this means a single command-line argument will be consumed and a single item (not a list) will be produced.`

`'?'. One argument will be consumed from the command line if possible, and produced as a single item. If no command-line argument is present, the value from default will be produced. Note that for optional arguments, there is an additional case - the option string is present but not followed by a command-line argument. In this case the value from const will be produced. Some examples to illustrate this:`

Details [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)

Comment: You don't need to specify '?' for a flagged argument unless you need the 3-way switch provided by the `const` parameter.   '?' for a positional should have a meaningful `default`.

Answer (score 1):

The first arg `csv_path` is required (you did not provide some default value), so you need to pass that to your command line like below:

```
python Train.py some_file.csv  # or the path to your file if it's not in the same directory
```

Comment: What i can insert to `csv_path` line?

Comment: Eg: 'home/hoang/coco' ??

Comment: @Wiliam yes, your csv path, if your csv file is in the same folder, you can just specify the name

Comment: ValueError: invalid option string 'csv_path': must start with a character '-'

Comment: i run with Pycharm

Comment: Try it without Pycharm and see if it works, just run `python Train.py path_to_your_csv_file.csv`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import argparse
import sys
import csv

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--file', default='fileName.csv')
args = parser.parse_args()
csvdata = open(args.file, 'rb')
```

Comment: Please put your answer always in context instead of just pasting code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.