# Python - How can i call the script with different command line arguments from within my IDE?

Tags: python, arguments, pycharm

I am doing a nudity detection using nueral networks for my final year project. So far i found a github link to finish my project. To run this project i need to pass 2 arguments such as `input_file` and `-m/--model_weights`. i am using Pycharm IDE. i found a [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33102272/pycharm-and-sys-argv-arguments) answer to pass argument. But in my case i need to pass arguments by using 2 lines of code. Not like giving parameter in Script Parameters box in pycharm. How can i do it?

> `input_file` means path of the image.
>
> `-m/--model_weights` means path of the weights.  in my case weights path
>   is `data/nsw_weights.npy.`

and this is my project file.

```
import sys
import argparse
import tensorflow as tf

from model import OpenNsfwModel, InputType
from image_utils import create_tensorflow_image_loader
from image_utils import create_yahoo_image_loader

import numpy as np


IMAGE_LOADER_TENSORFLOW = "tensorflow"
IMAGE_LOADER_YAHOO = "yahoo"


def main(argv):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument("input_file", help="Path to the input image.\
                        Only jpeg images are supported.")
    parser.add_argument("-m", "--model_weights", required=True,
                        help="Path to trained model weights file")

    parser.add_argument("-l", "--image_loader",
                        default=IMAGE_LOADER_YAHOO,
                        help="image loading mechanism",
                        choices=[IMAGE_LOADER_YAHOO, IMAGE_LOADER_TENSORFLOW])

    parser.add_argument("-t", "--input_type",
                        default=InputType.TENSOR.name.lower(),
                        help="input type",
                        choices=[InputType.TENSOR.name.lower(),
                                 InputType.BASE64_JPEG.name.lower()])

    args = parser.parse_args()

    model = OpenNsfwModel()

    with tf.Session() as sess:

        input_type = InputType[args.input_type.upper()]
        model.build(weights_path=args.model_weights, input_type=input_type)

        fn_load_image = None

        if input_type == InputType.TENSOR:
            if args.image_loader == IMAGE_LOADER_TENSORFLOW:
                fn_load_image = create_tensorflow_image_loader(sess)
            else:
                fn_load_image = create_yahoo_image_loader()
        elif input_type == InputType.BASE64_JPEG:
            import base64
            fn_load_image = lambda filename: np.array([base64.urlsafe_b64encode(open(filename, "rb").read())])

        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        image = fn_load_image(args.input_file)

        predictions = \
            sess.run(model.predictions,
                     feed_dict={model.input: image})

        print("Results for '{}'".format(args.input_file))
        print("\tSFW score:\t{}\n\tNSFW score:\t{}".format(*predictions[0]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: I think the approach that you are looking for is called Hyperparameter tuning. 

You need to call this script with another script that changes the weights and saves the outputs. Generally there are approaches to do this, or libraries to leverage. Take a look at these.

Comment: That's not what he is asking for. If I get it correctly, you are asking how you can call the script with different command line arguments from within your IDE?

Comment: @dennlinger exactly thats what i want. for an example:  **input_file = 'test.jpg'  ** and **weight_path = 'data/nsw_weights.npy'. **. i edited the question too..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pycharm and sys.argv arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33102272/pycharm-and-sys-argv-arguments)

Comment: @dennlinger i mentioned in  my question. i tried that answer and  its working. By the way in my case am trying to input image using GUI. so i need to set those arguments using 2 lines of code. am new to python and  i dont know how to do that? can you please help me

Answer (score 0):

In pycharm you can setup multiple run configurations which will allow you to pass in different arguments.

The documentation [has a section](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html) that shows you ways to set this up.

You may also want to consider writing tests if you have a set of specific inputs you want to confirm the results for.