# Run the code through console by pycharm

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm

Hi I am new to programming and pycharm. I want to run the code below through the python console. I need to enter 3 values to run it. I tried python p13.py one two three but it didn't work.

```
from sys import argv

script, first, second, third = argv

print "The script is called", script
print "Your first variable is:", first
print "Your second variable is:", second
print "Your third variable is:", third
```

Could you help me with what am I meant to type into the python consle in pycharm in order to run this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pycharm and sys.argv arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33102272/pycharm-and-sys-argv-arguments)

Comment: It works fine. make sure the python version is 2. try `python2 p13.py one two three`.

Comment: did you use pycharm?