# Python Argparse 'following arguments are required' error

Tags: python, pycharm, argparse

I'm trying to use a github repo and having some issues with the argparse part of the project. The repo starts like this:

```
import markdown, sys, csv, getpass, smtplib, argparse
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from jinja2 import Template


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-m', '--markdown', help='Path to Markdown Template', required=True)
parser.add_argument('-c', '--csv', help='Path to CSV file', required=True)
parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', help='Write out emails')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

I've entered both the relative and absolute path to both the markdown and CSV files... and I get in return this error:

```
usage: mass-email.py [-h] -m MARKDOWN -c CSV
mass-email.py: error: the following arguments are required: -m/--markdown, -c/--csv

Process finished with exit code 2
```

I can't find any specific help with this. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: How exactly did you run this? You didn't show the command line you were actually using.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pycharm and sys.argv arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33102272/pycharm-and-sys-argv-arguments)

Answer (score 2):

Call your script with `mass-email.py -m /path/to/my/file -c /path/to/csv`

Your arguments are defined by their flags. If you want your arguments to be positional, don't include the dashes before them.

```
parser.add_argument('markdown', help='Path to Markdown Template', required=True)
parser.add_argument('csv', help='Path to CSV file', required=True)
```

Comment: So there’s no way to run this from an IDE? I’m using pycharm

Comment: Two options: see Greg's answer or `parser.parse_args('-m /path/to/my/file -c /path/to/csv'.split())`

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you may be running it from the IDE without giving any command line arguments. I see you are using pycharm, so check this post about passing in command line arguments to pycharm runs:

[Pycharm and sys.argv arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33102272/pycharm-and-sys-argv-arguments)