# How to use the argparse module?

Tags: python, pycharm, argparse

This is part of my halftoning code and there is error make code unable run.

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser("Classical Half Toning [2x2 Mask]")
ap.add_argument('-i', '--image', required = True, help = 'Path to image file')
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

I get the error by running this code.

```
usage: Classical Half Toning [2x2 Mask] [-h] -i IMAGE
Classical Half Toning [2x2 Mask]: error: the following arguments are required: -i/--image
```

Comment: how is this an error? you declared the option required, is this happening when you call it with the -i option?

Comment: I don't know. That error come code when I run the code. What should I do

Comment: How exactly do you run it?

Comment: using Pycharm then Run the code. Sorry just new to coding

Comment: Do you know how to provide command line arguments?  Even what they are?  How are you starting this script?

Comment: Hey, I would suggest you check the docs of PyCharm [PyCharm-Docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html)

Comment: I just copy from this link https://github.com/shekkizh/ImageProcessingProjects/blob/master/PythonProjects/ImageManipulation/HalfToning.py

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51678855/901925 - pycharm

Answer (score 0):

Have you ran the particular command as followed in the terminal :

`python filename.py pathToImage`

Comment: Done try it. Still same outcome :(

Comment: What does ```python filename.py -h``` returns?

Comment: its return "show this help message and exit". But when I use -i IMAGE, the error change which is "AttributeError: module 'image_utils' has no attribute 'image_resize'"

Comment: for the final code statement use:              ```args = ap.parse_args() ```