# main.py: error: the following arguments are required: -i/--image

Tags: python, argparse

I am making a color detection application, using this tutorial: https://itsourcecode.com/free-projects/python-projects/color-detection-using-python-with-source-code/. I have followed it all the way through, but I get an error every time I try to run it. The error is: `main.py: error: the following arguments are required: -i/--image`. I've looked everywhere, but no one else seems to have this issue? My full code is:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import argparse

# Creating argument parser to take image path from command line
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument('-i', '--image', required=True, help="Image Path")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
img_path = args['image']

# Reading the image with opencv
img = cv2.imread(img_path)

# declaring global variables (are used later on)
clicked = False
r = g = b = xpos = ypos = 0

# Reading csv file with pandas and giving names to each column
index = ["color", "color_name", "hex", "R", "G", "B"]
csv = pd.read_csv('colors.csv', names=index, header=None)


# function to calculate minimum distance from all colors and get the most matching color
def getColorName(R, G, B):
    minimum = 10000
    for i in range(len(csv)):
        d = abs(R - int(csv.loc[i, "R"])) + abs(G - int(csv.loc[i, "G"])) + abs(B - int(csv.loc[i, "B"]))
        if (d <= minimum):
            minimum = d
            cname = csv.loc[i, "color_name"]
    return cname


# function to get x,y coordinates of mouse double click
def draw_function(event, x, y, flags, param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
        global b, g, r, xpos, ypos, clicked
        clicked = True
        xpos = x
        ypos = y
        b, g, r = img[y, x]
        b = int(b)
        g = int(g)
        r = int(r)


cv2.namedWindow('image')
cv2.setMouseCallback('image', draw_function)

while (1):

    cv2.imshow("image", img)
    if (clicked):

        # cv2.rectangle(image, startpoint, endpoint, color, thickness)-1 fills entire rectangle
        cv2.rectangle(img, (20, 20), (750, 60), (b, g, r), -1)

        # Creating text string to display( Color name and RGB values )
        text = getColorName(r, g, b) + ' R=' + str(r) + ' G=' + str(g) + ' B=' + str(b)

        # cv2.putText(img,text,start,font(0-7),fontScale,color,thickness,lineType )
        cv2.putText(img, text, (50, 50), 2, 0.8, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

        # For very light colours we will display text in black colour
        if (r + g + b >= 600):
            cv2.putText(img, text, (50, 50), 2, 0.8, (0, 0, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

        clicked = False

    # Break the loop when user hits 'esc' key
    if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Any help?

Comment: How are you invoking this on the command line?  What parameters are you setting when you run it if using an IDE?  The reason no one else gets this specific error is that _your_ code says the "-i/--image" parameter is required in line 8: `ap.add_argument('-i', '--image', required=True, help="Image Path")`  Likely duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51678520/python-argparse-following-arguments-are-required-error?rq=1

Comment: You need to provide the path of the image you want to process with flag `--image`. Let say your script name was `foo.py` then you need to run it from cmd as: `python foo.py --image <path-to-your-image>`

Comment: Do you know what it means to provide a commandline argument, such as the `--image path`?  Often we see errors like this because people try to run the script from some IDE, such as `spyder` or in a jupyter notebook.  Providing the value is most straight forward when running the script from a shell or commandline window.

Answer (score 1):

According to the tutorial, you have the following files on your file system:

```
some_directory/
              - Color_detection.py
              - sample.jpg
              - Colors.csv
```

To run, depending on what OS you are using, open your terminal in the directory where the files are and type:

```
python3 --version
OR
python --version
```

This will tell you what is the correct name for your python binary. I am going to assume python3 gives the correct answer and python throws an error. Then type:

```
python3 Color_detection.py -i sample.jpg
```

Explanation: -i (or --image) is an argument that is required, as observed in line 8 of the python script. It helps locate the image that the script is supposed to read. To view arguments at any time simply do:

```
print(arg)  # should output {'image': 'img.png'} if ran correctly
```

Cheers :)