# argument -m/--mode is required

Tags: python, argparse

when I run the program (this is not the entire program of course), an error appears "argument -m/--mode is required".

I do not know how to enter the argument -m or even -p ? I just run the program by pressing F5 and I am not asked to enter any m or p at any moment.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Crypto Arbitrage')
parser.add_argument('-m', '--mode', help='Arbitrage mode: triangular or exchange', required=True)
parser.add_argument('-p', '--production', help='Production mode', action='store_true')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: What's your development environment?

Comment: `F5` for what system?  An editor?  Pycharm, spyder?  Some sort of windows window?  Do you know what a command terminal is, in Wndows or Linux?

Comment: You may need to pull up some sort of `run` configuration window, and enter the commandline values there.  For example with `pycharm`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33102272/pycharm-and-sys-argv-arguments

Answer (score 0):

`parse_args`, by default, parses the arguments found in `sys.argv`, specifically `sys.argv[1:]`. If you were running the command from a command line, you would run your script with something like

```
python myscript.py -m exchange
```

which would automatically populate `sys.argv` with `['myscript.py', '-m', 'exchange']`. In your case (an interactive interpreter?), you may need to populate it explicitly before typing F5, for example,

```
sys.argv = ['myscript.py', '-m', 'exchange']
```