# sys.argv not passing more than one arguments

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, scheduling, or-tools

There is a project for staff scheduling using AI. I am having problem at `if len(sys.argv)<=1:`, sys.argv not passing more than 1 argument and only this condition gets true which gives output as

```
'Usage is main [section|sets|instructor|pairs|run] [seed]'
```

I want sys.argv gets 3 arguments so i can see how the rest of the program works.

my code

```
def main():
    import sys
    import random
    import tableutils
    print(len(sys.argv))
    nbcourse=7
    nbsets=6
    nbinstructor=5
    nbpairs=2
    if len(sys.argv)<=1:
        print('Usage is main [section|sets|instructor|pairs|run] [seed]')
        return
    elif len(sys.argv)>=3:
        random.seed(int(sys.argv[2]))
    S,nbsection=gen_section(nbcourse)
    R=gen_sets(nbsection,nbsets)
    I=gen_instructor(nbinstructor,nbsets,nbcourse,nbpairs)
    P=gen_pairs(nbpairs,nbsection)
    if sys.argv[1]=='section':
        tableutils.printmat(tableutils.wrapmat(S,[],['Id','Course id','Meeting Time']),True,0)
    elif sys.argv[1]=='sets':
        RR=[]
        for i in range(len(R)):
            RR.append([R[i][0],tableutils.set2string(R[i][1])])
        tableutils.printmat(tableutils.wrapmat(RR,[],['Id','Sections']),True,0)
    elif sys.argv[1]=='instructor':
        RI=[]
        for i in range(len(I)):
            RI.append([I[i][0],
                       tableutils.set2string(I[i][1]),
                       tableutils.set2string(I[i][2]),
                       tableutils.set2string(I[i][3]),
                       tableutils.set2string(I[i][4])])
        tableutils.printmat(tableutils.wrapmat(RI,[],['Id','Load','Course weights','Set weights','Pair weights']),True,0)
    elif sys.argv[1]=='pairs':
        RP=[]
        for i in range(len(P)):
            X=[str('(')+str(e[0])+str(' ')+str(e[1])+str(')') for e in P[i][1]]
            RP.append([P[i][0],tableutils.set2string(X)])
        tableutils.printmat(tableutils.wrapmat(RP,[],['Id','Section pairs']),True,0)
    elif sys.argv[1]=='run':
        rc,x,xs,v=solve_model(S,I,R,P)
        #tableutils.printmat(x)
        #print(xs)
        XS=[]
        for i in range(len(xs)):
            XS.append([xs[i][0], 
                       ['{0:2}'.format(e[0])+' : ('+'{0:2}'.format(e[1][0])+' '+'{0:2}'.format(e[1][1])+' '+'{0:2}'.format(e[1][2])+')' for e in xs[i][1]]])
        tableutils.printmat(tableutils.wrapmat(XS,[],['Instructor','Section (WC WR WP)']),True,1)
main()
```

I want this `elif len(sys.argv)>=3:` condition to get true what shall I do? 
I am running this program on pycharm idle

Comment: Pass at least 2 parameters to the program.

Comment: can you tell me where to pass the parameters?

Comment: @abdulwadood It depends on how you are running your script. If from a command line, simply add the arguments to the command line, like so: `myScript arg1 arg2 arg3`.

Comment: @chepner so i have passed some arguments from the run--> edit configuration--> script parameters and i have pass my class files which is "staff_scheduling.py" "tableutils.py" and now it gives 3 arguments but it gives error as ```random.seed(int(sys.argv[2]))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'staff_scheduling.py' ```

Comment: You appear to be confusing the set of modules required by your script with the command-line arguments; they are two very different things.

Comment: @chepner the parameters you should be passing are "run" "0" not the class files.  Your program should know where the class files are located if it has been installed correctly.

Comment: @John Yes, I'm pointing out that the OP *did* pass the module files, though, which is wrong.

Comment: @chepner  oops.  I meant to @ the OP.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

sys.argv[0] is always your program name.  If additional arguments are passed, len(sys.argv) will be > 1 with the subsequent elements of sys.argv containing the additional command line arguments.  It appears that you're running the script with 0 arguments and it's printing a message giving you options for required arguments.  If you're currently running

```
main
```

try running

```
main run 0
```

or some other permutation of the suggested arguments.

For passing arguments into a script when using PyCharm, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33102272/pycharm-and-sys-argv-arguments)

Comment: can you tell how to run like this i am using pycharm idle

Comment: I don't have any experience with PyCharm, but if you go to the command line on a unix-like system "python main run 0" (without the quotes) should work.  Edit:  found a link will update answer.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I tried passing the argument then it lead me into more errors guess i just had to leave it there. Thanks for your help anyway

Answer (score -1):

I choose that you will use argparse.
And, If you want to input 1 args, You will write to check 2.
    if len(sys.argv)<=2:

Because, sys.argv[0] is program name. ( ex. ~~.py )
So sys.argv always have 1 item.