# How to debug a python file on pycharm passing multiple params?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I'm sorry if it's a trivial question, but couldn't find an answer for.

I'm really new to python and decided to use pycharm because I used to work with intellij in my previous job (Java).

Well, I wanna debug the code in pycharm, and in order to debug a project without providing any parameter it was just straight forward, just double click on the python file and choose debug...

The thing is, in order to run the project that I'm working on I have to run the following code on terminal

```
clear; clientid=d57f00e-8a58-c9e647144947 clientsecret="gGO1XjHly/NQZZvTTWET=" keyvaultidentifier=ty-keyvault tenant=9091f191-4969-4532-82ba-f9a96db6f8a6 environment=dev python3 -m testing_server
```

My question would be: How can I make this command a running command where I can debug the code on pycharm?

I found an option Run > Edit configuration > Python, but somehow didn't really understood what to place where

[image]

Any tips? Sorry for the trivial question, it just it's taking too long to do something so simple.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you don't have any run configs, below is a screen shot of an example:[image]

Also, to use command line arguments, you can use the click module:

https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/

Comment: Can't thank you enough mate! It does work like a charm! Thank you! I would just  add that in order to work, I also had to import os, then used os.system("my command here") and boom! Worked!

Answer (score 0):

This Post is also answerd here: [Pycharm Run Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33102272/pycharm-and-sys-argv-arguments)

In the field Script Parameters put your Parameters inside, for exampale: "gGO1XjHly/NQZZvTTWET=" but dont forget the double quotes.

in the Field Interpreter options you are putting the flag to call, for example: -clientsecret

Answer (score 0):

you should create a new file like dev.py inside your settings folder like.

```
[projectname]/
├── [projectname]/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── [projectname]/
│   │   ├──settings.py
│   │   └──dev.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── manage.py
```

load it when the project is in debug mode. and that file would contain all these values.

```
clientid=d57f00e-8a58-c9e647144947
clientsecret="gGO1XjHly/NQZZvTTWET=" 
keyvaultidentifier=ty-keyvault 
tenant=9091f191-4969-4532-82ba-f9a96db6f8a6
```

and for debug. 
create a run config

like below

[image]