# argparse: Why do I get "the following arguments are required"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner in programming, I am using the example

```
import argparse
import pandas as pd

def read_data(fname):
    return pd.read_csv(fname)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    options = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    options.add_argument("-f", "--file", type=str, required=True)
    args = options.parse_args()
    data = read_data(args.file)
    print(data)
```

I got this error:

```
error: the following arguments are required: -f/--file
```

Would you please help me how can define my file name, where to write it?
Thank you

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. If you call it with the required arguments, there is no error.

Comment: Dear Friends , I am using Pycharm

Comment: What you're trying to convey by saying I am using PyCharm?

Comment: Well, find out how to pass arguments to the PyCharm debugger then. Or just run the code in the commandline: `python yourfile.py -f foo`

Comment: by debugger :     usage: main.py [-h] -f FILE
main.py: error: the following arguments are required: -f/--file

Comment: I run the code in commandline it is OK.    BUT if I want to run in Pycharm I think I have to define the filename in someway

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33102272/pycharm-and-sys-argv-arguments

Answer (score 2):

With `required=True`, the command-line must include the `-f` or `--file` arguments:

```
 # python myprog.py --file=somefile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `required=False`

```
options.add_argument("-f", "--file", type=str, required=False)
```

Comment: That won't work because the script makes later use of ``args.file``.  Presumably, the option was mark as required for good reason :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your original code would require `yourprogram -f filename.csv` where `yourprogram` is the name of your script file, and `filename.csv` is the name of a CSV file with input data.  The `-f` option can also be spelled out in longhand as `--file`.

But options should typically be optional. Make this a regular required argument if it is mandatory.

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("file", type=str)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    data = read_data(args.file)
    print(data)
```

Usage: `yourprogram filename.csv`

Perhaps you are using `python yourprogram.py` to run this script; then the usage would be `python yourprogram.py filename.csv`