# Using Argparse argument multiple times

Tags: python, pycharm, argparse

I'm completely new to Python and taking a beginner course right now. I'm getting the error when I run the code below: num_nums = len(args.n)
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Can someone help me figure this out since I have no idea what I'm doing? I'm also trying to figure out how take the "number to add" argument multiple times. Is using the nargs correct?

import argparse

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-n", type=int, nargs= '*', help="Number to add")
parser.add_argument("--indent", help="Indent output")

args = parser.parse_args()

num_nums = len(args.n)   
print("Adding %d numbers." % num_nums)    
sum = 0    
for n in range(0, num_nums):        
    sum = sum + args.n[n]

if (args.i):    
    print("\tSum = %d" % sum)    
else:    
    print("Sum = %d" % sum)
```

Comment: When debugging, include a `print(args)` line so you see exactly what the parser has produced.  Also show us what the calling commandline is.  My guess is that you have not provided a `-n 1 2 3` like argument. Your `args.n` is the default value, `None`.

Comment: Could you show how you attempt to run the program? Also, could you show us the course you are taking, so that we might review the instruction material? Maybe there's a specific part we can tell you to re-read more closely.

Comment: I'm using PyCharm to run this as it's the standard editor for our class.This is an introductory course for a cybersecurity program. I have no previous coding experience. Here is my instruction for this code: Take a look at the following piece of code.  Change the "number to add" argument to now be accepted multiple times so the loop doing the sum works correctly.  Also, resolve any mistakes that cause errors in the code

Comment: I think you have missed the instructions on how to supply commandline arguments when running a script from `pycharm`.

Comment: @jpaulj Can you explain that in more details?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/33102272/901925