# PyCharm debug console is read only, no command prompt

Tags: python, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I am using PyCharm 2021.2.4 on macOS Big Sur 11.6 with my interpreter running Python 3.9

My PyCharm debugger console displays as read only without the command prompt. I need the prompt so I can set the proper variables when I launch the script.

Here's what my debugger console looks like:[image: PyCharm debug console with no prompt]

Here's the prompt I'm expecting as per the Jet Brains documentation: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-debug-console.html#open

So far, I have tried:

1. Verifying that "Emulate terminal in console output" is deactivated as per: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000244824-Console-toolbar-is-gone?page=1#community_comment_115000347810
2. Installing PyCharm 2020.3 to check whether an earlier version exhibits the same behavior (it does).
3. Creating a conda environment using Python 2.7 as the interpreter.
4. Resetting the IDE to its default settings.

And in case it's relevant, I'm trying to run construal_level_task.py which is the file in this repo https://github.com/UOSAN/high_level_construal

At the command line, the file is launched with this command: `python3 construal_level_task.py --id ASH999 --run 1 --session 1` and those inputs (id, run, session) are the ones I'm trying to enter in the debugger console to run the script in debug mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The python program exited, so you cannot interact with the console any more. You need to set a break point in your code. Then the debug console will become interactive.

> those inputs (id, run, session) are the ones I'm trying to enter in the debugger console

Using the debug console is not the right way to enter inputs from command line arguments. Instead, you should edit the run configuration and add them there. See [Pycharm and sys.argv arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33102272/pycharm-and-sys-argv-arguments) for an explanation of how to do this.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right. I needed a run/debug configuration. I'm newish to Python and very new to PyCharm - really appreciate the help. Thanks!

Comment: @kdestasio To be clear, when you run or debug a python program, PyCharm automatically creates the run configuration. In this case, you need to edit that run configuration to include the arguments you want to pass to the python program.

Comment: yes, I should have specified that I set up the run configuration with the arguments specified under "Parameters". I also set the Python interpreter to the interpreter in the virtual environment I created for the project as per your recommendation in the other comment. That resolved a separate issue I was happening, so thank you again!

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is that you use conda interpreter. Is there a need for this? You can try using pure interpretator.

EDIT: Try to use virtual using normal interpreter (not conda). Your mistake is conflicting copies of conda envs.

Comment: I didn't initially even have a conda interpreter and have since removed it. I'm using my global interpreter in /usr/local/bin/python3.9 which is what I had setup initially.

Comment: If you look at your screenshot you will see the path to conda there when you run it

Comment: @kdestasio I highly recommend using conda or virtualenv rather than your global python interpreter and packages.