# PyCharm: running python file with arguments in console

Tags: python, pycharm, console

I recently updated PyCharm to its new version (2021.3.2) and realized that I cannot use the command `%run` anymore in a console to run a file. Previously, I was using such command with arguments as follows:

```
%run file.py --arg1 False --arg2 0.5
```

How can I do the same in the new PyCharm?

Comment: similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33102272/pycharm-and-sys-argv-arguments

Answer (score 1):

`%run` is a magic command from IPtyhon. I had to install the package in PyCharm to use such command.